# Ubuntu Phone image for aquaris e4.5 phone

Tags: phone

I Aufenthalts ordered the E4.5, Thinking it would be the Ubuntu edition,which was not the case. It came with kitkat installed.
My question is: is there a way to install ubuntu touch on this phone?

Thanks in advance!
Regards.